# Why are some of my characters surrounded by a grey swirl?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

Sometimes I have noticed that Sora (or anyone else in my party) will be walking around with this odd grey wispy swirling thing around them. What does it mean? Is it a good thing or a bad thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a good thing. Someone cast an [Aero-family](http://www.khwiki.net/Aero) spell. The spells have the following effects:

1. **Aero** - Halves damage taken. Duration is determined by adding 18 to your max MP.
2. **Aerora** - The above + damage on contact with enemies. Damage is determined by doubling your max MP value, and adding 6.
3. **Aeroga** - Above + it will deflect some attacks.

Below is a picture of Aeroga in action.

[image: Aeroga in action]

Information taken form [the wiki linked above](http://www.khwiki.net/Aero).

Comment: And a .gif to boot, nice!

Comment: Don't forget, higher levels (aeroa, aeroga) also reflect and cause damage as well.